# BLE on Qt 5.8 : MacOS as a peripheral device

Tags: c++, macos, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Qt 5.8 Beta version, that has added the Qt Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral support to the OSX devices.

My aim is to use bluetooth to transfer real time data from my macbook(peripheral device) to my iPhone(Central Device) using QT BLE. I went through the limited(but sufficient) tutorial for this, and worked out the following code for OSX Peripheral device advertising services.

```
void BlueToothDeviceDiscovery::advertisePeripheralDevicePresence(){
QLowEnergyAdvertisingData advertisingData;
advertisingData.setDiscoverability(QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::DiscoverabilityGeneral);
advertisingData.setIncludePowerLevel(true);
advertisingData.setLocalName("MyServer");
qDebug()<<advertisingData.discoverability();
const QScopedPointer<QLowEnergyController> leController(QLowEnergyController::createPeripheral());  //const QScopedPointer<QLowEnergyService> service(leController->addService(serviceData));
leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData,
                               advertisingData);
}
```

I am not able to discover my mac from my mobile phone. I guess I am not advertising the presence of OSX device properly. Any suggestions on how I get it right would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about QT BLE, but I can't see where you are advertising a specific BLE service; you will need to advertise a service and characteristic(s) on that server in order for the iOS app to be able to find anything.  Your Mac won't appear in the Bluetooth settings on the iOS device, you will need to run an app.  You can test with LightBlue

Comment: Thanks Paul..the code was incomplete..I added the advertising command..Let me try with LightBlue now..